# Automaticly create UV Map with correct aspect ratio

Tags: uv

I'm trying to texture my model using a single texture and i wan't to unwrap my meshes so that they overlap and can still use the full texture while keeping their correct aspect ratio and realtive size compared to each. How do i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Adding a picture to your question will help us answer best according to your model.

Comment: It's a good idea to check UV mapping first on test textures - Color Grid or UV Grid because it's very easy to see any deformations of that texture in the viewport / render. After mapping is checked you may continue with main texture,

Comment: Did you apply the scale of the object before unwrapping?

Comment: Nope, that solved it, thanks! It's now nearly perfect, the rest can be done manually. Do you wanna create an answer?